# How to visualize intermediate feature layers in keras?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, visualization, keras, deconvolution

I've read the paper [Visualizing and Understanding Convolutional Networks by Zeiler and Fergus](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.2901) and would like to make use of their visualization technique. 
The paper sounds promising - but unfortunately, I have no idea how to implement it in Keras (version 1.2.2).

Two questions:

1. Keras only provides the `Deconvolution2D` Layer but no `Unpooling` and no "reverse ReLU" Layer. How can I make use of those switch variables mentioned in the paper in order to implement the unpooling? 
   How do I have to use the reverse ReLU (or is it just the "normal" `ReLU`)?
2. Keras `Deconvolution2D` layer has the attributes `activation` and `subsample`. 
   Maybe those are the key for solving my problem?! 
   If yes, I would have to replace all my combination of Layers `Convolution2D` + `Activation` + `Pooling` with a single `Deconvolution2D` Layer, right?

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

The authors of the paper you cite (as far as I remember) talk briefly on how to handle this, specifically:

1. ReLU. The inverse of ReLU is... ReLU. Since convolution is applied to activation function in the forward pass, deconvolution should be applied to rectified reconstructions in the backward pass.
2. Pooling. There is no way to invert pooling strictly speaking. To cite the paper, "we can obtain an approximate inverse by recording the locations of the maxima within each pooling region in a set of switch variables. In the deconvnet, the unpooling operation uses these switches to place the reconstructions from the layer above into appropriate locations, preserving the structure of the stimulus."

Now, closer to actual implementation and Keras, have a look at [this thread](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/378) - you will find there some examples that you can use immediately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, I still don't understand how to implement this paper (I've tried your given links and also tried to make use of Devoncolution2D by trial and error. But the results are just images that are totally red (colormap = jet)). This paper would lead to some great visualizations...

Comment: In your question you're asking how to do this - and I provided an answer. It's rather hard to comment on why all your images are red - that's implementation issue. As explained, inverse of ReLU -> ReLU, while provided link has code snippet for Unpooling.

Comment: Yep, I got it. I used ReLU as activation function within the Deconvolution2D layers. 
Also I used subsample for doing the Unpooling. 
I will keep it rolling and share my solution (if I succeed).